# sms compress in android

Tags: java, android, sms, compression

How can we compress sms to get it into 160 char limit in android.

1. is it possible : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/erP922RXvCI
2. gzip not useful [output string is longer then input string.]
3. what about LZMA ?  it has huge dictionary size.
4. any other algo which can be usefull here ?

Answer (score 0):

A pretty good method would be to use [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). It's simple to implement and I think it's the most efficient coding system for text that only looks at character frequency. If I was going to try compress SMSs, I'd use this. You can relatively easily achieve a 50% compression rate.

Comment: Huffman coding is based on frequency of chars. i m not sure if it'll provide good compression ratio for such small text as sms. still i'll try and experiment with it. thanx Mike

Comment: Cool. What I'd do is pick a static coding tree for coding and decoding. Otherwise you need to send the tree in some way. There will be an optimal tree per language.

Comment: any good implementation available online ? or do i need to develop one myself .

Comment: I'm not sure about one online. When I wrote one, it took about 5 hours maybe but that was doing dynamic tree generation as well, but wasn't doing the bit-packing properly afterwards. So, if you've chosen a static tree, all you need to do is implement a tree-walk to find the bit pattern and then package the bits.